Installing MarkLogic Unit Test Without Modules Database
In my experience with MarkLogic Unit Test I have always had my modules under src/main/ml-modules. However, I have a ml-gradle project where we do not have a modules database and instead use a path to the xqy files on our local machines. I was thinking that we would have problems trying to use MarkLogic Unit Test because of this fact. When trying to install MarkLogic Unit Test, after adding the dependency in build.gradle and trying to run gradle mlLoadModules, I get the following error:
Error occurred while loading REST modules: Error occurred while loading modules; host: localhost; port: 8505; cause: Local message: config/resources write failed: Internal Server Error. Server Message: Server (not a REST instance?) did not respond with an expected REST Error message.

I am guessing this is because ml-gradle can't write the files to our local like it can when using a modules database. Has anyone been able to setup MarkLogic Unit Test without having your modules in a ml-gradle project/modules database?

The error you're getting isn't due to ml-gradle, but rather than the marklogic-unit-test library includes a REST extension. The use of REST extensions requires a modules database. That REST extension is one of two interfaces for marklogic-unit-test - the other being the fairly old web-based test runner.
One workaround you could consider is adding a REST API app server solely for running your marklogic-unit-test tests, and that app server would have a normal modules database.
